# Data Reference Not Valid error Excel when moving pivot table to existing worksheet

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel workbook, and created a pivot table. I now want to move this pivot table to an existing worksheet in the same workbook. When I try to do so, I get the following error message.

I also receive this message when creating a new pivot table and trying to place it in an existing worksheet. Instead, I have to create a new sheet to place the pivot table in.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply give the reference with selecting the cells. Excel will do the rest automatically.

Comment: just to clarify; instead of selecting just the worksheet, select the specific cell range within that worksheet where you want it placed?